# Select default option in a dropdown contained in other variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen infinity of post to try to choose by default an option in a dropdown. But I have not been able to achieve it. I have an array of some countries.

```
$scope.regions = 
 [
  {
    name: "COLOMBIA",
    id: 5
  },
  {
    name: "ARGENTINA",
    id: 6
  },
  {
    name: "BRAZIL",
    id: 7
  }
 ];
```

I have this variable:

```
$scope.selectThisId={
 "id":6,
 "animal":'dog',
 "variable":'xxx32'
};
```

I need the dropdown value to be equal to the id attribute of the

```
$scope.region=$scope.selectThisId.id;
```

variable.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rQRapq4MyPWhevXGYa7u?p=preview

Comment: Why are you asking the exact same question when it is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

You must to change id to code and in $scope.region need to be equal $scope.selectThisId only.

[Follow the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ub5M2QinYdS3YC4TmHeb?p=preview)

```
angular.module('angularApp', [])
  .controller('controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.regions = [{
      name: "COLOMBIA",
      code: 5
    }, {
      name: "ARGENTINA",
      code: 6
    }, {
      name: "BRAZIL",
      code: 7
    }];

     $scope.selectThisId={
    "code":6, // code here
    "animal":'dog',
    "variable":'xxx32'
 };

    // selected value by default is 'argentina'
    //$scope.select = $scope.regions[1];
    $scope.select = $scope.selectThisId; // the object here
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter to your controller to get the default region (don't forget to add `$filter` after `$scope`):

```
$scope.defaultValue = $filter('filter')($scope.regions, {code: $scope.selectThisId.id}, true)[0];
```

and then add this to your select in your view

```
ng-init="select = defaultValue"
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nmc8iLz6BIFac0Swfth8?p=preview)